# Запятая при двух последовательных деепричастиях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия

**И лишь под вечер, возвращаясь от знакомого(,) и видя уведомление о пяти непрочитанных сообщениях, где были фотографии ран и вопросы, из-за чего они могли появиться, он понял, что было не так тем вечером.**

Нужна ли здесь запятая? Или когда два деепричастных оборота подряд, то их не надо разделять? Не поставить запятую — это грубая ошибка?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, полное предложение - без этого не видно, к одному ли глаголу относятся два оборота.

Comment: И лишь под вечер, возвращаясь от знакомого (,) и видя уведомление о пяти непрочитанных сообщениях, где были фотографии ран и вопросы, из-за чего они могли появиться, он понял, что было не так тем вечером.

Comment: Под **вечер** он понял, что было не так тем **вечером**. Вечер еще не наступил, а он уже понял про него все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь запятая не нужна, поскольку оба деепричастных оборота относятся к одному глаголу, однородны (как однородные обстоятельства) и объединены союзом "и".

> Если два однородных деепричастных оборота соединены одиночным союзом
>   и, да в значении «и», или, либо, то перед союзом запятая не ставится,
>   а деепричастные обороты обособляются вместе, как один.
>
> *Я, вдавившись в клеенчатую спинку дивана и закрывая глаза, мечтал.
>   (М.А. Булгаков. «Театральный роман»)*

https://lampa.io/p/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-00000000456eef278222ff90e9d8ca19

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна, как уже было сказано, но **вызывает сомнение стилистика предложения,** например, такие выражения: ***видя уведомление, он понял.*** Что-то здесь не так с последовательностью действий, ведь на самом деле он сначала увидел уведомление, потом прочитал сами сообщения и только после этого, поразмыслив, понял.

Возможный вариант:

И лишь под вечер, **возвращаясь от знакомого  и прочитав** пять новых сообщений, где были фотографии ран и вопросы, из-за чего они могли появиться, он понял, что было не так тем вечером.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил тире "на переломе" предложения, для ясности: *И лишь под вечер, возвращаясь от знакомого и прочитав пять новых сообщений, где были фотографии ран и вопросы, из-за чего они могли появиться, — он понял, что было не так тем вечером.*

Comment: Да, хороший вариант.